# replace elements in a data frame with variables in another

Tags: r

i have a data-frame with character elements in it. i need to replace the elements by referring to another data-frame. The column names for data-frame 1 could be anything, will have to replace the data without referring to column names.

```
 data-frame_1                         data-frame_2

Jan-12  Feb-12                       rating  Order
 ab       ac                          ab      1
 ac       ab                          ac      2

apply(data-frame_1,2,function(x){mapvalues(x,data-frame_2$rating,data-frame_2$Order)})
```

i have tried using apply function but its not working.
I'm trying to get this output

```
 data-frame_1                        

Jan-12  Feb-12                       
   1       2                          
   2       1
```

Comment: Try `setDT(df1)[df2, Feb-12 := Order, on =  .(Jan-12 = rating)]`

Comment: the thing is column name for data-frame 1 could be anything. i have to replace the data irrespective of column names

Comment: Please check the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `match`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) df2$Order[match(x, df2$rating)])
```

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(df1, function(x) df2$Order[match(x, df2$rating)])
#     Jan-12 Feb-12
#[1,]      1      2
#[2,]      2      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Jan-12` = c("ab", "ac"), `Feb-12` = c("ac", "ab"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(rating = c("ab", "ac"), Order = 1:2), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *lookup vector* using `setNames`:

```
lup  <- setNames(df2$Order, df2$rating)
df1[]  <- lup[unlist(df1)]
df1
#  Jan-12 Feb-12
#1      1      2
#2      2      1
```